# Modeling struct for INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, go, inner-join, slice

I have two tables one is the `order` table, and the other is the `order_items` table. Using an `INNER JOIN`, I try to join the columns together to create a new slice when calling all the orders. But the `order_items` is a slice and does not come out well.

This is the full code: https://go.dev/play/p/OoqL_JX3yZX. What I am trying to do is to group the `order_items` according to the `order_id` to achieve this result.

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "delivery_fee": "50660.45",
    "subtotal": "50600.88",
    "total": "656600.44",
    "products": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 1,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 4,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:12:27.247305Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 2,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 2,
            "quantity": 1,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:12:27.247305Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        }
    ],
    "id": 2,
    "delivery_fee": "50660.45",
    "subtotal": "50600.88",
    "total": "656600.44",
    "products": [        
        {
            "order_item_id": 3,
            "order_id": 2,
            "variation_id": 1,
            "quantity": 10,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:13:09.996713Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 4,
            "order_id": 2,
            "variation_id": 2,
            "quantity": 8,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:13:09.996713Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the result I am getting is this:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "delivery_fee": "50660.45",
    "subtotal": "50600.88",
    "total": "656600.44",
    "products": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 1,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 4,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:12:27.247305Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 2,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 2,
            "quantity": 1,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:12:27.247305Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 3,
            "order_id": 2,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 10,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:13:09.996713Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 4,
            "order_id": 2,
            "variation_id": 2,
            "quantity": 8,
            "order_status": "pending",
            "order_date": "2022-11-05T10:13:09.996713Z",
            "customer": "admin2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I believe that the problem might be from the `INNER JOIN` in the SQL query.

These are my structs:

```golang
type AllOrders struct {
    ID          int64           `json:"order_id"`
    DeliveryFee decimal.Decimal `json:"delivery_fee"`
    Subtotal    decimal.Decimal `json:"subtotal"`
    Total       decimal.Decimal `json:"total"`
    Product  []Product     `json:"products"`
    Date        time.Time       `json:"order_date"`
    Owner       string          `json:"customer"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID          int64     `json:"order_id"`
    OrderID     int64     `json:"order_item_id"`
    ProductID int64     `json:"product_id"`
    Quantity    int64     `json:"quantity"`
    Status      string    `json:"order_status"`
    Date        time.Time `json:"order_date"`
    Owner       string    `json:"customer"`
}
```

For the SQL CRUD function:

```golang
-- name: ListOrdersItem :many

SELECT * FROM orders A
INNER JOIN order_items B
ON A. id =B. order_id;

const listOrdersItem = `-- name: ListOrdersItem :many

SELECT a.id, a.owner, a.status, delivery_fee, subtotal, total, a.created_at, b.id, b.owner, order_id, variation_id, b.status, quantity, b.created_at FROM orders A
INNER JOIN order_items B
ON A. id =B. order_id
`

type ListOrdersItemRow struct {
    ID          int64           `json:"id"`
    Owner       string          `json:"owner"`
    Status      string          `json:"status"`
    DeliveryFee decimal.Decimal `json:"delivery_fee"`
    Subtotal    decimal.Decimal `json:"subtotal"`
    Total       decimal.Decimal `json:"total"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    ID_2        int64           `json:"id_2"`
    Owner_2     string          `json:"owner_2"`
    OrderID     int64           `json:"order_id"`
    ProductID int64           `json:"product_id"`
    Status_2    string          `json:"status_2"`
    Quantity    int64           `json:"quantity"`
    CreatedAt_2 time.Time       `json:"created_at_2"`
}

func (q *Queries) ListOrdersItem(ctx context.Context) ([]ListOrdersItemRow, error) {
    rows, err := q.db.QueryContext(ctx, listOrdersItem)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    items := []ListOrdersItemRow{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var i ListOrdersItemRow
        if err := rows.Scan(
            &i.ID,
            &i.Owner,
            &i.Status,
            &i.DeliveryFee,
            &i.Subtotal,
            &i.Total,
            &i.CreatedAt,
            &i.ID_2,
            &i.Owner_2,
            &i.OrderID,
            &i.ProductID,
            &i.Status_2,
            &i.Quantity,
            &i.CreatedAt_2,
        ); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        items = append(items, i)
    }
    if err := rows.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return items, nil
}
```

I apologize for the long code, but I have been banging my head for weeks on how to solve this. I have tried some other SQL queries but they all produce a result far from what I want. That was why I had to stick to `JOIN`. How do I achieve the result I want?

Comment: Hey @pythonGo can you please give correct/working(which give wrong o/p as you said) code link, so might help you.

Comment: Hello @UmeshSonawane. Thanks for the response. The above lines of code works, there are no errors. The only problem I have is that the response I am getting is not the desired response. The response I want to achieve is different from what the for loop and the inner join is giving me. So I was hoping maybe someone could point me to the right direction to achieve the desired result. Will edit the question now to clearly point out the desired response.

Comment: *"What I am trying to do is to group the order_items according to the order_id to achieve this result."* -- Your desired result is **NOT** valid JSON. You can't have a JSON object with duplicate *keys*. Same goes for Go structs, you can't have a single struct value hold more than one instance of the struct's type. Did you mean to use slices for orders and arrays for the json objects? If not, if what you've shown is what you actually want to do, then you're out of luck. Rethink and redesign.

Comment: Hello @mkopriva. So glad you saw this question. Most of your answers here on go and SQL have really helped me in times I ran into errors. I intend to use slices for the orders and arrays for the json objects like you said. List all the orders as an Array alongside the order items as a slice.

Comment: If you want to use a slice of Go structs to represent the orders then you should not use `AllOrders`, it's a bad name unless what you mean for that type to represent is some kind of aggregated value. You should have a struct to represent an order_item, e.g. `OrderItem` and a struct to represent an order, e.g. `Order`, then to represent "all orders" you'd use `var allOrders []*Order` instead.

Comment: This is what I want to do. Thanks so much for the suggestion. Will try to do it this way and give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `struct` type is a perfect fit for representing a relational database's table row (also known as *tuple*). So, in general, it is a good idea to have a struct type for each table whose data you want to represent in your Go program. For example, if your database has a table called `orders` and another called `order_items`, then your Go program should have the corresponding `Order` and `OrderItem` struct types that will be used specifically to represent the records in those two tables.

```golang
type Order struct {
    ID       int   `json:"id"`
    Total    int64 `json:"total"`
    SubTotal int64 `json:"subTotal"`
    Fees     int64 `json:"fees"`
    // ...
    Items []*OrderItem `json:"items"`
}

type OrderItem struct {
    ID       int `json:"id"`
    OrderID  int `json:"orderID"`
    Quantity int `json:"quantity"`
    // ...
}
```

---

Selecting records from two joined tables where the relationship is one-to-many is, in my opinion at least, best done in two separate steps with two separate queries. For example:

```golang
query1 := `SELECT
    id
    , total
    , sub_total
    , fees
    ...
FROM orders
WHERE ...`

rows1, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, query1, args...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer rows1.Close()

var orders []*Order
var ordersByID = make(map[int]*Order) // will be used by order_items rows loop
for rows1.Next() {
    order := new(Order)
    err := rows1.Scan(
        &order.ID,
        &order.Total,
        &order.SubTotal,
        &order.Fees,
        // ...
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    orders = append(orders, order)
    ordersByID[order.ID] = order
}
if err := rows1.Err(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Note that the `JOIN` below is *only* necessary if some of the `orders` table's columns need to be used in the `WHERE` condition, or if some of those columns need to be included in every single `OrderItem`. If *none* of the above applies to your use-case then omit the `JOIN`.

```golang
query2 := `SELECT
    i.id
    , i.order_id
    , i.quantity
    ...
FROM order_items i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id=i.order_id
WHERE ...`

rows2, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, query2, args...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer rows2.Close()

for rows2.Next() {
    item := new(OrderItem)
    err := rows2.Scan(
        &item.ID,
        &item.OrderID,
        &item.Quantity,
        // ...
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // append the item to the correct order
    order := ordersByID[item.OrderID]
    order.Items = append(order.Items, item)
}
if err := rows2.Err(); err != nil {
    return err
}

// At this point the orders slice declared in the previous
// snippet will contain all the orders will all their items.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am using SQLC to generate the CRUD function. I have tried to pass in the query with the **LEFT JOIN**, but i am lost on how to integrate this into my flow. Using SQLC, ``-- name: GetOrderItemstack :many

SELECT *
FROM order_item i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id=i.order_id; `` . and for the order slice `` -- name: GetOrders :many
SELECT *
FROM orders
ORDER BY id;``So i now have two queries like you said. But i am lost on how to make it a function on its own. I tried to use another for loop inside this function ````

Comment: I am using SQLC to generate the CRUD function. but i am lost on how to integrate this into my flow. Using SQLC, ``-- name: GetOrderItemstack :many

SELECT *
FROM order_item i
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id=i.order_id; `` . and for the order slice `` -- name: GetOrders :many
SELECT *
FROM orders
ORDER BY id;``So i now have two queries like you said.  I tried to use another for loop inside this function `` func (server *Server) getOrders(ctx *gin.Context) {rsp1, err := server.store.GetOrders(ctx) rsp2, err := server.store.GetOrderItemstack(ctx)}``

Comment: I am lost really. I am relatively new to golang. So sorry for the noob replys.

Comment: @pythonGo I don't use sqlc and I don't know sqlc. So I don't know if the approach I have suggested can easily be implemented with the use of sqlc.

Comment: Actually, the Left Join you proposed is amazing. And earlier you said i had to redesign/rethink. I did over a few hours and the **LEFT JOIN** gives me the orderItems with the order which fits the new design i thought of. In the frontend, the users only needs to see the orderItem and not the Orders. So i was even thinking of the whole thing in the wrong way. Thanks so much.

Comment: So having two functions is the correct implementation for me. Instead of forcing it into one function.